# Not hide soft-deleted instances while using `get_or_create`

Tags: python, django, django-models

Let's say you are modifying get_queryset in you manager something like this

```
class VoteManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self):

        return super().get_queryset().filter(is_deleted=False)



class Vote(models.Model):

    objects = VoteManager()
```

This works as expected but the problem when you use something like `get_or_create` on Vote model it creates an instance even if it is present in the database because we modified the get_queryset() method. Can we not shadow the soft-deleted instance while creating??

Comment: If you use Vote.objects.get_or_create(), your filter not applied?

Comment: The only method you want to not hide soft-deleted instances in queryset is `get_or_create`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try override get_or_create method too. Like this:

```
class VoteQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):

   def get_or_create(...):
      """Your realization"""


class VoteManager(models.Manager):

   def get_queryset(self):

      return VoteQuerySet(model=self.model, using=self._db, hints=self._hints).filter(is_deleted=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

`get_or_create()` is a method from `Queryset` (check [this](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py#L528)). One way to solve this problem is [create your own queryset class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/2.1/topics/db/managers/#creating-a-manager-with-queryset-methods) and overwrite this method to not hide the soft-deleted instances.

Another way is create a manager and override `all()` method adding a flag to return all items from database (even soft-deleted instances), like this:

```
class VoteManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(is_deleted=False)

    def all(self, force_all=False):
        if force_all:
            return super().get_queryset()  # queryset with all items
        return self.get_queryset()         # queryset without soft-deleted items
```

Now you can call `get_or_create()` and soft-deleted instances will not be hidden.

```
Vote.objects.all(force_all=True).get_or_create(**data)
```

`Vote.objects.all(force_all=True)` returns a queryset with all items from database. You can call methods over this queryset like `filter()`, `get_or_create()`, `update_or_create()` and soft-deleted instances will not be hidden.